# displaying a zero with sprintf %s

Tags: php, wordpress, printf

I'm working over a wordpress theme which has this code in a php form.

```
    $other_fields = array(
        __( 'Budget', APP_TD ) => sprintf( '%s (%s)', appthemes_get_price( $project->_hrb_budget_price, $project->_hrb_budget_currency ), $budget_text ),
        __( 'Location', APP_TD ) => ( 'remote' != $project->_hrb_location_type  ? $project->_hrb_location : __( 'Remote', APP_TD ) ),
        __( 'Files', APP_TD ) => $files,
    );
```

In the front end if I type 0.01 in the budget box it comes up with an error saying 'please insert a valid budget price'.

The box won't allow me to start the price with a 0?

I want to allow Bitcoin prices in the box so want the user to be able to type in i.e 0.1 for example.

Is there anyway around this?

Thanks!

Comment: sprintf is not going to say "please insert a valid budget price". That's something else in WP doing that...

Comment: There is this near the top of the php file.

if ( empty( $_POST['budget_price'] ) || ! intval( $_POST['budget_price'] ) ) {
   appthemes_add_notice( 'invalid-price', __( 'Please insert a valid budget price.', APP_TD ) );
        }

Comment: I can put in i.e 1.05 in the box and that displays fine. It's just not allowing me to start my price with a 0.

If I put in 01.5 it shows as 1.5 etc.

Comment: I just removed that last bit of code above and it's working as it should! :-) Thanks Marc B!

Comment: Do NOT remove the whole condition, the problem is with intval. intval(1.05) translates into 1 which translates into TRUE, intval (0.5) translates into 0 which translates into FALSE. Use is_numeric() instead.